# How to send print() output directly to a file with Dart Editor?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I read those [ch04-tools-editor](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-editor.html), [get-started](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/get-started/) and searched on Google, but I didn't find any answers. How to send print() output directly to a file with Dart Editor?

EDIT : I want to send (pipe/redirect stream) the data (what print() return) directly in a file, instead the Dart Editor. I'm looking for a feature of the Dart Editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`print()`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core.html#print) doesn't output to files; it outputs to the console (`stdout` in console apps, the browser console in browsers).

The [`dart:io`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io.html) library offers plenty of functionality for I/O, including reading and writing files.  One example:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  var out = new File('output.txt').openWrite();
  out.write("String written to file.\n");
  out.close();
}
```

**Update:** As per your updated question, you're looking for a Dart Editor feature that automatically writes console output to a file.  To the best of my knowledge, there's no such feature.  Your options include:

1. Manually write to a file as demonstrated above.
2. Copy the console output from Dart Editor.
3. Run your app from outside Dart Editor.  On any UNIX-like system, for example, you can redirect `stdout` like this:

   ```
   dart my-app.dart >output.txt
   ```
4. Modify Dart Editor (it's open source) to add the feature you want.

Comment: Thanks.  I left an edit to explain more what I'm looking for.