# Running a jar file using Dart:IO Process class?

Tags: dart

Why is this code not returning any results?

```
Process.run('java', ['-mx300m -classpath stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model stanford-postagger/models/wsj-0-18-bidirectional-nodistsim.tagger -textFile stanford-postagger/sample-input.txt']).then((ProcessResult results) {
    print(results.stdout);
});
```

I get no error when the code is executed either.

Comment: You should handle errors through [Future.catchError](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Future.html#catchError).

Comment: I added .catchError((e)=>print(e)); but no error was captured. @CedX

Comment: Also, add a call to `print(results.stderr)` in your `then` handler. Do you have any output from `results.stderr` or `catchError` handler ?

Comment: @Cedx Yes. Now I got this: Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx300m -classpath stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model stanford-postagger/models/wsj-0-18-bidirectional-nodistsim.tagger -textFile stanford-postagger/sample-input.txt
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a common Java error. It's a good idea to set the minimum and maximum heap size to the same value. In any case, don't let the minimum heap size exceed the maximum heap size.

Note: the second argument to `Process.run` is an array. Use an element for each command line argument instead of an array containing only one long string.

```
Process.run('java', [
  '-Xms300m', // Set minimum and maximum heap size to the same value
  '-Xmx300m', // Set minimum and maximum heap size to the same value
  '-classpath',
  'stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar',
  'edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger',
  '-model',
  'stanford-postagger/models/wsj-0-18-bidirectional-nodistsim.tagger',
  '-textFile',
  'stanford-postagger/sample-input.txt'
]).then((ProcessResult results) {
  print(results.stdout);
  print(results.stderr);
})
.catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
```

Comment: I've added an argument to save output to a file but I get an unknown argument error. Any idea what is wrong?                       ` '>',
                       'stanford-postagger/tagged-output.txt'`

Comment: Nevermind. I've got what I'm looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243065/how-to-send-print-output-directly-to-a-file-with-dart-editor